# How to convert a java bean to json?

Tags: java, json, smartgwt

I am using smart GWT for an application. I want to pass a bean to the client as a response. Is there any way to convert a java bean into json data. Or if someone has some different approach to do this then please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the json: there are libraries like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) that allow you to convert beans to json and back.

If you don't have a Java bean but want to create json use libraries like [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

There might be better ways in GWT but I'm no expert and thus I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: +1 for gson for ease of use. It's literally as simple as `String json = new Gson().toJson(myBean);`